# Honeywell thermostat hookup with No C wire with wires RC, RH, G, W, Y currently used, how How to hookup external wall adpater transformer

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

How Do I hookup Honeywell RTH8500 thermostat with No  C wire with wires RC, RH, G, W, Y currently used? I have an external wall adpater transformer but don't know where to connect it to. I have separate Heating and Cooling (Heating is a Weil McLain Boiler for Hot water baseboard and Hot water(no tank) and Cooling is a separate unit that was added later.)

RC Cool

RH Heat

W Heat

Y Cool

G Cool

Comment: What model of thermostat are you dealing with, and can you post photos of the wiring at each end?

Comment: Honeywell RTH8500

Comment: It does not answer the question on where or what to do with the second wire from the external transformer.

Comment: @Machavity -- not a dupe -- he is using a two transformer configuration vs the normal single transformer config

Comment: Can you post pictures of the wiring at the boiler end?

Comment: If you can't get all the pictures in, post links to them in a comment and we can edit them in for you :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8mHxQyprf3sbkRqZjVRNUlkVFE?usp=sharing     all pictures are here